# Sort API methods in Swagger-UI

Tags: java, jax-rs, swagger, swagger-ui

I cannot find any working example, how to achieve the following:
I want my API methods in the Swagger-UI sorted either by methods (GET-POST-PUT-DELETE) OR/AND alphabetically.

So far, all methods are displayed in a random order, even not in the order given my source code.

I use Jax-RS + Jersey 1.

Sorting using the position attribute of @ApiOperation is not an option for me, as there are too many methods and the API is still extending, so I would need to update all if there is a new one.

Any hints?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update for Swagger UI  2.1.0+:** The `sorter` parameter has been split into two parameters, as noted in [Fix 1040](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1040), [Fix 1280](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/pull/1280):

> apisSorter
>
> Apply a sort to the API/tags list. It can be 'alpha'
>   (sort by name) or a function (see Array.prototype.sort() to know how
>   sort function works). Default is the order returned by the server
>   unchanged.
>
> operationsSorter
>
> Apply a sort to the operation list of each API. It can be 'alpha' (sort by paths alphanumerically), 'method' (sort by
>   HTTP method) or a function (see Array.prototype.sort() to know how
>   sort function works). Default is the order returned by the server
>   unchanged.

So you'll want to update `sorter` to `apisSorter` to sort the API list alphabetically, and/or `operationsSorter` to sort the operations list of each API. The pet shop demo has updated to apisSorter, as shown below:

[Example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/src/main/html/index.html): ([working demo](http://petstore.swagger.io/), sorted alphabetically)

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({

...

apisSorter : "alpha"
});
```

**For Swagger UI versions older than 2.1.0**:

The `sorter` parameter is still relevant for older versions of Swagger UI:

You can use the *sorter* parameter when instantiating SwaggerUi. This happens in the javascript on the Swagger-Ui index.html. From the [documentation](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-ui#swaggerui):

> sorter apply a sort to the API list. It can be '**alpha**' (sort paths
>   alphanumerically) or '**method**' (sort operations by HTTP method).
>   Default is the order returned by the server unchanged.

[Example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/97ed093e6ec3a7a778ac6a41d76775c88b1fc951/src/main/html/index.html):

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({

...

sorter : "alpha"
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be the solution I was looking for! Unfortunately I can't get it working, neither with 'alpha', nor 'method'. Migrated to Jersey-2 in the meantime, using swagger.js 2.0.30 and swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10 1.3.4 now. Any idea, if that should be working with this configuration?

Comment: Ok, the sorter param seems to be quite new. I also updated my swagger docs to the ones from your link (swagger.js 2.0.41) and that works with the sorter parameter! Pretty cool:)

Comment: Thanks it's the best solution for me too !

Comment: for tag sorting, it's `tagsSorter` now. `tagsSorter: "alpha"`

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer is a bit outdated. In newer versions it is done by:

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({

...

apisSorter: "alpha", // can also be a function
operationsSorter : "method", // can also be 'alpha' or a function
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that update! Could you add a hint, which version it refers to?

Comment: Unfortunately I can only confirm that this works in version 2.1.1. That is currently online and I'm also using it like this. It is also documented here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/README.md . But I can't say, when they changed it and since when the other one is outdated :(

Comment: for tag sorting, it's `tagsSorter` now. `tagsSorter: "alpha"`

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue and I fixed it like this

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    apisSorter: "alpha", 
    operationsSorter: function (a, b) { 
    var order = { 'get': '0', 'post': '1', 'put': '2', 'delete': '3' }; 
    return order[a.method].localeCompare(order[b.method]);    
  },
});
```

Comment: Which version do you use? Is this also 2.1?

Answer (score 2):

**Update for Swagger 3.18.3**

```
 window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
           ...
            operationsSorter: function (a, b) {
                var order = {'get': '0', 'post': '1', 'put': '2', 'delete': '3'};
                return order[a.get("method")].localeCompare(order[b.get("method")]);
            },
           ...
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update for 3.x+**

As also mentioned in comments previously, `apisSorter` seems to have been renamed to `tagsSorter` in v. 3.x, see [Swagger configuration documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/).

```
window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  ...
  tagsSorter: "alpha",
  operationsSorter: "alpha"
  ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort **api tags** and **operations** in nestjs you can pass [SwaggerCustomOptions](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/interfaces/swagger-custom-options.interface.ts#L5) to `SwaggerModule.setup()` method in following way:

```
import { DocumentBuilder, SwaggerModule } from '@nestjs/swagger';

//...

const config = new DocumentBuilder().addBearerAuth().build();
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
SwaggerModule.setup('api/docs', app, document, {
  swaggerOptions: {
    apisSorter: 'alpha',
    tagsSorter: 'alpha',
    operationsSorter: 'alpha',
  },
});
```

Comment: May duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974561/nestjs-alphabetize-endpoints-in-swaggerui

Answer (score 0):

For .net Core users with SwaggerUI3:

```
 app.UseSwaggerUi3(j=>j.TagsSorter = "alpha");
```

Comment: What about ordering the API methods where controller/method_name is not used in the route as `[HttpGet("{id}")]` and `[HttpGet]`? I tried this approach, but does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

For Python folks who end up here with the same issue, here's how to solve it

**Using flasgger v0.9.5 (=Swagger-UI 3.28.0) and Flask v2.0.1:**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
config = {
    "ui_params": {
        "operationsSorter": "alpha",  # sorts endpoints alphabetically within a tag
        "tagsSorter": "alpha". # sorts tags alphabetically
    }
}
Swagger(app, config=config)
```

Answer (score 0):

With my version of swagger i've managed to do like this:

```
apisSorter: "alpha", 
operationsSorter: function (a, b) { 
    var order = { 'get': '0', 'patch': '1', 'post': '2'};
    return order[a._root.entries[1][1]].localeCompare(order[b._root.entries[1][1]]);
}
```