# swagger-ui sort API not working Version 1.3.12

Tags: api, sorting, playframework, swagger-ui

I want to sort my API method in alphabetical order.

Int the doc it say that you just have to put :

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
        // ...
        sorters : "alpha" // or sorter I've tried both
      });
```

The post is already related [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951268/sort-api-methods-in-swagger-ui).

But in my case this is not working at all and it is today quite difficult to find an API in swagger-UI.

And if I don't know if I update my swagger-ui version if i need to upgrade swagger too. In this case I cannot do this...

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have to upgrade my swaggerUI version, no choice... Thanks you [Salem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1205368/salem)

Answer (score 0):

From their [GitHub page](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui), the correct key seems to be `apisSorter` and not `sorters`:

```
window.swaggerUi = new SwaggerUi({
    // (...)
    apisSorter : "alpha"
});
```

Comment: yes I've seen that, but it doesn't work with my current swagger-ui version. I've forgot to mention that...

Comment: @hamdalaye Which swagger-ui version are you using?  I can't find that version (1.3.12) on their [releases](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/releases) page

Comment: I am using version 2.1.0-alpha.7. The  1.3.12 is the swagger-play2.version in my pom.xml : <swagger-play2.version>1.3.12</swagger-play2.version>
        <swagger-play2-utils.version>1.3.12</swagger-play2-utils.version>