# Swagger API Operations Ordering

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

How do I sort my operation by method alphabetically e.g. **DELETE**, **GET**, **POST**, **PUT**.

I have read from this post but it is in HTML but in my case, I have integrated Swagger into Spring Boot so I need to sort it when creating a Docket.

[Sort API methods in Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951268/sort-api-methods-in-swagger-ui)

Then I noticed this method `operationOrdering()` in Docket, but I still cannot make it work.

Answer (score 10):

With **Spring Boot 2.4** and **OpenAPI** the following properties in **application.properties** may be of interest:

- springdoc.swagger-ui.**tagsSorter**=alpha
- springdoc.swagger-ui.**operations-sorter**=alpha

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a difference between: `springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=alpha` & `springdoc.swagger-ui.operations-sorter=alpha` but the former is used on their docs:https://springdoc.org/faq.html#_how_can_i_sort_endpoints_alphabetically

Comment: `operations-sorter` sorts the endpoints from one class, `tags-sorter` sort the classes inside swagger ui. With both of them you sort first the class title, and inside each one, the endpoints.

Answer (score 8):

I am using Springfox version 2.8.0 and following code snippet works for my documented API:

```
@Bean
UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder
            .builder()
            .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.METHOD)

            ...

            .build();
}
```

There are 2 possible values:

- `OperationsSorter.ALPHA` - sorts API endpoints alphabetically by **path**
- `OperationsSorter.METHOD` - sorts API endpoints alphabetically by **method**

`OperationsSorter.METHOD` is what you are looking for.

---

**Alternative** by using `operationOrdering()`:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .select()
        .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
        .paths(PathSelectors.any())
        .build()

        ...

        .operationOrdering(new Ordering<Operation>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Operation left, Operation right) {
                return left.getMethod().name().compareTo(right.getMethod().name());
            }
        })
}
```

However, this does not work because of a bug in Springfox which seems to be still active ([Operation ordering is not working](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1648)).

Comment: @DanielHári do you mean the `OperationsSorter` or the alternative?

Comment: Neither of them works, it sorts all operations by url.

Comment: @DanielHári I am using Springfox version 2.9.2 in my project and the `OperationSorter` method works for me. Both `ALPHA` and `METHOD`. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: Here is my config that not works: https://gist.github.com/haridaniel/0e8c9ae63ff8daac866c2b6ff53ccc2c

Answer (score 4):

```
@Bean
public UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
    return UiConfigurationBuilder
            .builder()
            .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.METHOD)
            .build();
}
```

This works for me. I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.0.M6, Swagger UI 2.9.2

Answer (score 0):

`springdoc.swagger-ui.operations-sorter` does not work in  `v3/api-docs`.

For  alphabetical ordering in `v3/api-docs` use :

```
springdoc.writer-with-order-by-keys=true
```

Comment: this alphabetically sorts schema properties also along with the http method.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application.properties file

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method
springdoc.swagger-ui.tagsSorter=alpha
```

Result :
[image]