# How to order API endpoints with Swagger annotations (Springfox)

Tags: java, spring, swagger, springfox

I want my controller endpoints marked with `@ApiOperation` to come in a certain order in the Swagger spec. Tried to set `position` on `@ApiOperation` like this:

`@ApiOperation(value = "xxx", position = 1)`

seems to have no effect on the result. Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger API Operations Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801387/swagger-api-operations-ordering)