# Custom Swagger endpoint by desire method order with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I am using swagger 2.9.2 version and i want to display endpoints like 
Get, Post, Put, Patch, Delete.
I referred this post 
[Swagger API Operations Ordering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41801387/swagger-api-operations-ordering)
which is must similar to my requirement and it working in ascending order but I want to display endpoint as mentioned above order.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors
                        .basePackage("com.xxx.xxx.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build()
                .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .apiInfo(metaData());
    }   
    private ApiInfo metaData() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("test data")
                .description("test data")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }   
    @Bean
    UiConfiguration uiConfig() {
        return UiConfigurationBuilder
                .builder()
                .operationsSorter(OperationsSorter.METHOD)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What should work is something like this:

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            ...
            .build()
            .operationOrdering(new Ordering<Operation>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(final Operation left, final Operation right) {
                    // Here you have all the information about the operations, 
                    // such as left.getMethod(), right.getMethod()
                    // and you may implement the sorting on your own.
                    // Return +1, 0 or -1 based on the expected order.
                }
            });
}
```

However, based on the link you provided https://stackoverflow.com/a/52760718/2886891 there might still be a bug:

> However, this does not work because of a bug in Springfox which seems to be still active ([Operation ordering is not working](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1648)).

Comment: Honza Zidek Thanks for reply, I tried given example but it is not working with me.

Comment: Create a MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and if you are sure it is still an error, post it at https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues.