# How do I manually order the endpoints displayed on Swagger UI?

Tags: java, java-8, swagger-2.0

I'm using Docket to configure my Swagger 2 instance.
But the only Options I currently see are to sort by Type (POST, GET, etc.) or by endpoint name (a-z).

There is a logical order to my endpoints and I'd like to display them in that order

#### What I want:

```
POST /start
POST /uplaod
POST /finalize
POST /checkStatus
```

#### Instead I get something like this:

```
POST /checkStatus
POST /finalize
POST /start
POST /upload
```

#### Code:

```
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .host(swaggerHost)
                .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {

                    @Override
                    public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                        return swaggerBasePath;
                    }
                })
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(Api.class))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .securitySchemes(Collections.singletonList(securitySchema()))
                .securityContexts(Collections.singletonList(securityContext()));
    }
```

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/41801387/8929501

Comment: No, that's the opposite of my question.

Comment: I'm trying to manually order them, not auto-sort them.

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52760718/8929501
That answer states that you can use `operationOrdering()` to manually order

Comment: That sorts it alphabetically by method name, not by a manual order.

Comment: Additional clarification, "method" in this context is POST/GET/etc. it is not the Java method name.

Comment: You will have to implement your custom ordering inside that `public int compare(Operation left, Operation right)` method. It's similar to implementing a sort order with the `compareTo` of `Comparable`

Comment: I started to try that, but it didn't appear to have the endpoint names readily available to use for ordering. Do you happen to know which `left.methodNameHere()` would have that info?

Answer (score 3):

Sorting operations in Swagger UI - Sort by **specific http verb order**, then by **path**

For example, the Swagger UI accepts configuration from a configuration object passed as an argument to Swagger UI (`SwaggerUI({ ... })`)

```js
const swaggerUI = SwaggerUI({
    operationsSorter: function (a, b) {
        const order = {
            'get': '0', 'post': '1', 'patch': '2', 'put': '3', 'delete': '4',
            'head': '5', 'options': '6', 'connect': '7', 'trace': '8'
        };
        return (
            order[a.get("method")].localeCompare(order[b.get("method")])
            || a.get("path").localeCompare(b.get("path"))
        );
    }
});
```

See https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

Comment: Where is `operationsSorter` supposed to be setup?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to order the endpoints for swagger UI is to use tags: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/grouping-operations-with-tags/

Edit: adding the alternative I use to address a comment below: I tend to use the operationsSorter with a custom comparison function. Example:

```
operationsSorter: function (a, b) {
  var order = {'get': '0', 'post': '1', 'patch': '2', 'put': '3', 'delete': '4'};
  if (a.get('path') == b.get('path')) {
    return order[a.get('method')].localeCompare(order[b.get('method')]);
  }
  if (a.get('path').split('/').length == b.get('path').split('/').length) {
    return a.get('path').split('/').slice(-1)[0].localeCompare(b.get('path').split('/').slice(-1)[0]);
  }
  return a.get('path').split('/').length - b.get('path').split('/').length;
}
```

Comment: And how do you sort the endpoints inside the tag? E.g. what if you have 10 endpoints with same tag - how are those sorted?

Comment: @StijnV have added a comment above