# API methods Sorting : Swagger version 3.0.2

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

I am using [swagger version 3.0.2](http://swagger.io/swagger-ui/) , I have also followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32345035/3006390) but there was no effect on the method order.

```
window.onload = function() {

  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  .....
  apisSorter: "alpha",
  layout: "StandaloneLayout"
})
```

Can any one tell the best way to change the order of the API methods.

Comment: I think v3 does not support this for now. You can open an issue in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues).

Comment: @Helen IS there any type of hint that i can change in the code by my self for sorting.

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Swagger UI 3.0.7 added support for 2.x's `operationsSorter` parameter that controls method sorting inside each API/tag.

> operationsSorter
>
> Apply a sort to the operation list of each API. It can be 'alpha' (sort by paths alphanumerically), 'method' (sort by HTTP method) or a function (see Array.prototype.sort() to know how sort function works). Default is the order returned by the server unchanged.

```
const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
  url: "http://petstore.swagger.io/v2/swagger.json",
  ...
  operationsSorter: "alpha"
})
```

The `apisSorter` parameter is not yet supported in 3.x.