# Swagger-ui v3.0.2: API methods sorting

Tags: sorting, swagger, swagger-ui

API method `sorting` has a known issue in v3.0.2, about which I have already posted on Stackoverflow [question refernce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42977003/3006390) and on Github [issue reference](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2818).

I am looking for some temporary work around for the time being. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API methods Sorting : Swagger version 3.0.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42977003/api-methods-sorting-swagger-version-3-0-2)

Comment: @Helen: its known duplicate question reference is already mentioned in the question but looking for some temporary work around for the time.

Comment: An answer containing a workaround would still be a suitable answer for your original question. Please don't post duplicate questions.