# NestJS Alphabetize Endpoints in SwaggerUI

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui, nestjs-swagger

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951268/sort-api-methods-in-swagger-ui) shows that SwaggerUi will sort endpoints alphabetically if it is passed `apisSorter : "alpha"` when instantiated. In NestJS the config options are passed in the `SwaggerModule.createDocument`. I cannot see where in the config [eg here](https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/master/lib/document-builder.ts) I can pass this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can pass it as the fourth parameter to the `SwaggerModule.setup` method like so:

```js
const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, options);
  SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, document, {
    swaggerOptions: {
      tagsSorter: 'alpha',
      operationsSorter: 'alpha',
    },
  });
```

`swaggerOptions` is `untyped` which is why you just have to know what you're passing.  Found the answer [in the discord server](https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/606125276845441034/755263731557990460) so hopefully that link doesn't expire.

Comment: this works thanks I had seen https://github.com/nestjs/swagger/blob/ae3c35556522dc0dc2f42f769093861443ec5607/lib/interfaces/swagger-custom-options.interface.ts#L3, but wasn't sure that was the right key...I had tried passing the hash directly, which of course didn't work

Answer (score 0):

To anyone trying [@midopa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576186/jay-mcdoniel)'s [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64974803/4567986) for FastifySwagger, pass the `tagsSorter` and `operationsSorter` values to `uiConfig` instead of `swaggerOptions`.

```ts
    const doc = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);
    SwaggerModule.setup('docs', app, doc, {
    uiConfig: {
      tagsSorter: 'alpha',
      operationsSorter: 'alpha',
      },
    });
```

**NOTE**: This is for @nestjs/swagger version 6 or less. For v7 or above, `swaggerOptions` will work just fine.

Comment: that atributte not found in nest js swagger version 7 above

Comment: The answer has been edited to add the version for which this solution was necessary. For @nestjs/swagger v7 or above, `swaggerOptions` will work. Thank you for directing my attention to this.