# How to sort methods by method type in FastAPI Swagger API?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

How can I set a sort order for the API methods in the FastAPI Swagger autodocs? I would like all my methods grouped by type (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951268/sort-api-methods-in-swagger-ui) shows how to do it in Java. How can I do it in Python?

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def list_all_components():
    pass

@app.get("/{component_id}")
def get_component(component_id: int):
    pass

@app.post("/")
def create_component():
    pass

@app.put("/{component_id}")
def update_component(component_id: int):
    pass

@app.delete("/{component_id}")
def delete_component(component_id: int):
    pass
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify why the answer doesn't work in python? Do you have a link to docs that show how you're using it in python?

Comment: The linked answer is written in Java. I am looking for a pure Python solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [configure Swagger UI parameters through the FastAPI constructor](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#change-default-swagger-ui-parameters).

```py
app = FastAPI(swagger_ui_parameters={"operationsSorter": "method"})
```

The [full list of parameters can be found in the swagger documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/).

[image]

Comment: Any idea if there's a way in Python to use a custom sorting method?

Comment: I'm guessing you'll have to implement a custom openapi schema in that case and reorder the routes returned from `get_openapi` as shown here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/extending-openapi/#generate-the-openapi-schema - you can also implement a custom sort in Javascript and give that function to operationsSorter, but you can't include it from the `swagger_ui_parameters` property - so I think you'll have to do a custom openapi endpoint for that as well. I might have time to dig further into it later.

Comment: Since the answer is more involved and nuanced, I've asked a separate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72915808/how-to-create-a-custom-sort-order-for-the-api-methods-in-fastapi-swagger-autodoc