# Sort rest api operation - Swagger spring doc

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc

I want to sort rest api based on custom sorter depending on the rest verb, so it will be (Get, Post, Patch, and delete) under any path, How I could achieve that programmatically or via yaml configuration

Tech:
org.springframework.boot version '3.0.6'

org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui:2.1.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort API methods in Swagger-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951268/sort-api-methods-in-swagger-ui)

Comment: @Ahbishek, this sort operation by alphabetics, what I want is to sort, on custom arrange (Get, Post, Patch, Delete)